# How to push code to 2 github repositories at the same time?

Tags: git, github, repository, config, push

I want to **push the same code from my local** using git + vscode **to two github repos** with only one command **without individually specifying each remote**.

I have **tried** adding 2 remote repos in the **config file**:
*Updated config file:*

```
cat config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:profile1/-MS_E-commerce_Grus_Tep_Online_Full-time_2021_1.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "github"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*
        url = git@github.com:profile2/e-commerceAPI.git
        pushurl = git@github.com:profile2/e-commerceAPI.git
```

Now when I do `git push` it **only pushes to one repo**, this one

> profile1/-MS_E-commerce_Grus_Tep_Online_Full-time_2021_1.git

I have tried using `git push -u github main` but it throws an error:

> error: src refspec main does not match any,
> error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:profile2/e-comm..

I have tried with `git push -u origin main`.
But, I'm completely unfamiliar with the process and this is my 1st attempt. Please suggest. I could also go for a way to push it with multiple steps every time as long as my commits are preserved.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `git push` command only pushes to one (1) repository, each time you run it.  You pick the (as in, **one**) repository that it should push to, at the time you run it, using the argument `origin` or `github`, given your two `remote`s:

```
git push origin
```

or:

```
git push github
```

The former connects to:

```
url = git@github.com:profile1/-MS_E-commerce_Grus_Tep_Online_Full-time_2021_1.git
```

and the latter connects to:

```
pushurl = git@github.com:profile2/e-commerceAPI.git
```

It uses the `pushurl` setting since it *has* a `pushurl` setting; as `origin` lacks such a setting, it uses the `url` setting instead.

In either case, having made this connection, the set of commits and other objects that your `git push` will send, and the set of requests it will make *to* whoever answers at the URL, will depend on the last argument.  So if you want to send your `master` branch commits each time, and have the GitHub repository update *its* `master` branch each time, you would use `master` each time:

```
git push origin master
git push github master
```

You *should* run *two* commands to update two remotes.  This allows you to detect which one failed, if one fails.

> I want to push the same code from my local using git + vscode to two github repos with only one command **without individually specifying each remote**.

<s>You can't do that.</s>  It turns out that `git push` *will* do this, but it's not documented.  As such, it could potentially stop working in the future.  It's certainly safer to do something else: You can, for instance, set up an *alias* or *script* that contains the two commands, and run the alias or script, at least from the command line.  Whether, and how, you can do this from the mouse in VS, I have no idea.

To do this with Git, simply set two or more `url`s or `pushurl`s under any one given `remote`, e.g.:

```
[remote "pushpair"]
    pushurl = git@github.com:profile1/-MS_E-commerce_Grus_Tep_Online_Full-time_2021_1.git
    pushurl = git@github.com:profile2/e-commerceAPI.git
```

Running `git push pushpair master` will now try to push to each of the two pushurl settings in sequence.  Either can fail; Git will still try the remaining one if one fails.  This is based on the Git source code, not the documentation.

(Note that if you use one `pushurl`, any `url` settings are ignored, so both must be a `pushurl`.  If you use `url` without `pushurl`, and set multiple URLs, all will be used.  However, it's not clear how `git fetch` will behave here.)

Comment: OP> "*I want to push the same code from my local using git + vscode to two github repos with only one command without individually specifying each remote.*" torek> "*You can't do that.*? `git remote set-url origin --push --add`, no? Like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3195446/7976758

Comment: @phd: Interesting. It's not documented, and I wouldn't trust it even if I'd tested it and found it worked. However, checking the source code, it will actually work. The lack of documentation is worrisome. I'll update the answer.